# Expand information in one dataframe and link with data from other

Tags: python, dataframe, linker, expand

Lets say I have dataframe as such:

```
df1

Index   Id
ABC     [1227, 33234]
DEF     [112, 323, 2223, 231239]
GHI     [9238294, 213, 2398219]
```

And another one:

```
df2

Id        variable
112       500
213       78073
323       10000000
1227      12
...
9238294   906
```

My goal is to expand df1['Id'] to connect it with respective value from df2['variable'] to do comparisons of within values of variables from df2 for each Index from df1.

Data at hand has large volume.

What's the most efficient way to expand information from df1 and ascribe value from df2['variable']?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, do you want to get a new column in df1 that contains a list of df2 variable based in if the id in in df2 is in the df1 Id list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` `df1` and `merge` it with `df2` on `Id`:

```
out = df1.explode('Id').astype({'Id':int}).merge(df2.astype({'Id':int}), on='Id')
```

Output:

```
  index       Id  variable
0   ABC     1227        12
1   DEF      112       500
2   DEF      323  10000000
3   GHI  9238294       906
4   GHI      213     78073
```